# Automorphisms of the group of integers $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone help me showing $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z_2$?

I guess I should define an homomorfism $\phi:\mathbb Z\longrightarrow S(\mathbb Z)$ with kernel $2\mathbb Z$ and image $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)$. Here $S(\mathbb Z)$ are the bijections of $\mathbb Z$. However I wasn't able to do that.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I presume you're considering group automorphisms here?

Comment: Exactly man =)..

Comment: if $f \in Aut({\mathbb Z})$ then show $f(n) = n f(1)$. When can this be surjective?

Comment: an automorphism takes generating sets to generating sets.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)$. We have
$$
\varphi(n) = \varphi(\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{n \text{ times}}) = \underbrace{\varphi(1) + \cdots + \varphi(1)}_{n \text{ times}} = n \ \varphi(1).
$$

Thus, $\varphi$ is completely determined by its value at $1$. Only two values make $\varphi$ surjective, $1$ and $-1$. It follows that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)$ consists of two elements. In other words, $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can you explain better the statement "only two values make $\varphi$ surjective, $1$ and $-1$"?

Comment: Since $\varphi(n) = n \varphi(1)$, we have $\varphi(\mathbb Z) = \varphi(1) \mathbb Z$. Only for $\varphi(1) \in \{1, -1\}$ we have $\varphi(1) \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: All right, I agree =) Thanks..

Comment: @ptf Another way to see this: If $G$ is cyclic, an isomomorphism $h:G\to H$ must map generators of $G$ to generators of $H$, and is completely determined by the image of any generator.  In this case we have $G=H=\Bbb Z$ and there are exactly two generators, namely $1$ and $-1$.  So an isomorphism of $G$ to itself must map $1\mapsto 1$ or $1\mapsto -1$; these completely determine the two automorphisms.